# How to reduce number of calls to TemplateHandler in Handlebars with CollectionFS?

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Anyone have any ideas to reduce the calls to BioPic in my Handlebars template (using Meteor). {{cfsFileUrl}} is a CollectionFS helper that requires a current file context, hence without {{#with BioPic owner}} it won't work. It just seems a bit redundant to have to call BioPic twice.

```
<template name="showBioPic">        
    {{#if BioPic owner}}
        {{#with BioPic owner}}
            <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'size48x48gm'}}" alt="Profile Picture: {{_id}}">
        {{/with}}
    {{else}}
        <img class="showShared" src="images/default-biopic-48x48.png" alt="Default Profile Picture">
    {{/if}}
</template>


Template.showBioPic.BioPic = function (IN_ownerId) {
   return BioPicsFS.findOne( { owner: IN_ownerId });
};
```

Here's the CollectionFS git / docs:
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{{#with}}` block helper accepts an `{{else}}` block. So you can just do:

```
<template name="showBioPic">
    {{#with BioPic owner}}
        <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'size48x48gm'}}" alt="Profile Picture: {{_id}}">
    {{else}}
        <img class="showShared" src="images/default-biopic-48x48.png" alt="Default Profile Picture">
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my hack workaround, using a global var to avoid the duplicate call. To quote The Who, "Man there's got to be a better way".

```
<template name="showBioPic">        
    {{#if BioPic owner}}
        {{#with foundBioPic}}
            <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'size48x48gm'}}" alt="Profile Picture: {{_id}}">
        {{/with}}
    {{else}}
        <img class="showShared" src="images/default-biopic-48x48.png" alt="Default Profile Picture">
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

JavaScript

```
// Template GLOBAL
var currentBioPic = null;


Template.showBioPic.BioPic = function (IN_ownerId) {

   console.log("BioPic: IN_ownerId = " + IN_ownerId);

   currentBioPic = BioPicsFS.findOne( { owner: IN_ownerId });

   return currentBioPic;
};

Template.showBioPic.foundBioPic = function () {
   return currentBioPic;
};
```